"Cayley's theorem" for abelian groups?
Cayley's theorem says that any group embeds into $S_n$, the symmetric group, i.e. permutations of a set, i.e. $\operatorname{Aut}_{\text{Set}}(n)$, for some cardinal $n$.
From general algebra, we also know that any abelian group embeds into $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^n$ for some cardinal $n$, where the exponent here means direct product, not direct sum.
Is there a way to generalize the argument used to prove Cayley's theorem to abelian groups to achieve this result or a similar result?
Edit: I should elaborate on the proofs that I am aware of for the second fact.
The first time I was exposed to this concept was Aluffi's Chapter 0 in the context of injective modules and homological algebra. I am pretty sure the proof does not require any such machinery, but I referenced back to it while writing this post and I found that Aluffi leaves the details vague on how one goes from "every abelian group embeds into $\mathbb{Q}^{\oplus n}/K$ for some $K \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^{\oplus n}$" to the result I quoted. This intermediate result might be the better one to relate to Cayley's, so I should throw it out there.
The second time I was exposed to this concept was when working through an exercise from Burris and Sankappanavar's A Course in Universal Algebra. In this text, we see that every algebraic structure (subdirectly) embeds into the product of its variety's subdirectly irreducibles. One of the exercises was to compute the subdirectly irreducibles for the variety of abelian groups, and I found they are precisely the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}$ (the Prüfer $p$-groups). It is a well-known fact that the direct sum of these groups is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, so this recovers the result I stated.
I don't know if the proof Aluffi is alluding to is essentially the same as the proof I know via universal algebra. Either way, I hope this edit to my question clarifies where I'm coming from.

Cayley's theorem has a very easy proof. We just use the left multiplication map. The other result is different and has nothing to do with Cayley's theorem.

@DietrichBurde maybe that is true, but this question is asking whether there might be some unexpected connection. If you have a good reason to believe it is impossible, I'd be interested to see it as an answer.

Well, in Cayley's theorem you get $n$ out as (at most) the cardinality of the group. Are you hoping the two $n$s in the two theorems will be connected? I'm not familiar with the proof of the second fact, but it doesn't sound like it will be. For instance $\mathbb{Z}_n$ embeds into $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, but not into $S_1$.

@preferred_anon that the $n$'s come from the same place is not necessary to me, although hopefully the $n$ is counting something. I was thinking about talking about the proofs I am familiar with, so I will edit the post accordingly.

The embedding you are mentioning is usually seen as a consequence of the fact that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a cogenerator of $\mathbf{Ab}$. This means that for homomorphisms $f,g : B \to A$, if $hf = hg$ for all $h : A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, we have $f = g$. It can also be formulated as follows: The canonical homomorphism
$$A \to \prod_{f \in \hom(A,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})} \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},\quad a \mapsto (f(a))_f$$
is a monomorphism. So if $n$ is the number of homomorphisms $A \to (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^n$, we get a monomorphism $A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. But the converse also holds: assume that in any category with products there is an object $C$ such that every object $A$ admits an embedding into $C^n$ for some cardinal $n$. Then $C$ is a cogenerator in that category.
This means that your question is equivalent to: is there a formal argument like for Cayley's "Theorem" which shows that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a cogenerator? The answer is a big No.
That $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a cogenerator of $\mathbf{Ab}$ is by no means formal. It also relies heavily on the axiom of choice. The complete proof can be found, for example, here. Even that $\mathbf{Ab}$ has any cogenerator is not obvious at all. Not every abelian category has a cogenerator. Even an AB5 abelian category does not necessarily have one. Also, $\mathbf{CRing}$ and $\mathbf{Grp}$ don't have any cogenerators.
At least, one can prove that every Grothendieck abelian category has an injective cogenerator. You can find the proof in Kashiwara-Schapira, Theorem 9.6.3 (and the original one in Grothendieck's Tohoku paper). The proof is not constructive, though. The cogenerator is constructed via transfinite recursion.
I hope this makes clear that this far beyond Cayley's "Theorem" (not sure why we call it a theorem, it is a baby case of the Yoneda Lemma, and both are formal, I assume it is just for history reasons).

This is a very good answer, thank you! I have several comments on how this clarified things in my head: Firstly, this clarifies why Aluffi might have called Q/Z "cofree": it is clear that Z is a generator of Ab, and it is "free". Secondly, this shows how the resemblance to Cayley's theorem is entirely coincidental. Thirdly, the proof using Universal Algebra that I know indeed uses Zorn's Lemma to prove the subdirect embedding theorem, so now I see this was not superfluous for this specific case. The lingering question I do have is whether Grp has a cogenerator, but I'm sure I can google this.

Based on this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646123/cogenerator-in-category-of-groups-monoids-rings it seems that there is "too many subdirectly irreducibles" for there to ever be a cogenerator of Grp. Ab barely has any subdirectly irreducibles, so it does have a cogenerator (using choice, of course).
